# TabView with ScrollView in sheet disables scroll down to dismiss

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project, and I've encountered an issue with a TabView inside a sheet. It seems that when I add ScrollView instances within the TabView, the ability to scroll down to dismiss the sheet is disabled.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {}
      .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
        TabView {
          ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
              Text("Item \(i)")
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
            }
          }
          .tag(0)
          
          ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
              Text("Item \(i)")
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
            }
          }
          .tag(1)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
      }
  }
}
```

In the above code, I have a ContentView that presents a sheet containing a TabView with two ScrollView instances. The issue is that when I open the sheet, I cannot scroll down to dismiss it. Instead, the scrolling is trapped within the ScrollView.

Is there a way to allow scrolling down to dismiss the sheet while retaining the scroll functionality within TabView and ScrollView?

Answer (score -1):

Adding `.padding(.top, 50)` to the `TabView` worked for me. Let me know if it worked for you

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {}
    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
      TabView {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
          ForEach(0..<100) { i in
            Text("Item \(i)")
              .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
          }
        }
        .tag(0)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
          ForEach(0..<100) { i in
            Text("Item \(i)")
              .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
          }
        }
        .tag(1)
      }
      .padding(.top, 50)
      .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code. Try this out - it should work

Comment: It just adds the top padding. Drag down to dismiss still doesn't work in ScrollView.

Comment: Yeah so if you scroll down from the top padding it'll dismiss the sheet. If you want the scrolling within the `ScrollView` itself to dismiss it then it's not possible. You have to swipe down on the sheet itself and top padding adds a little area where you interact with the sheet instead of the scroll view. Try swiping down from the padded area itself

Comment: Please don't mislead people. Just remove the TabView and you can drag down to dismiss sheet from the ScrollView. It's just a bug and I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: You are correct my apologies. I wasn't aware you could do that if you remove the tab view. Anyways best of luck finding a solution. The padding trick is working on my device so hopefully that helps you find what you're looking for